# Testing Zend Framework controllers that return HTML5

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I have a controller test case that looks like the following:

```
class LoginControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public function testLoginFormIsShown()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/login');
        $this->assertQuery('form#login');
    }
}
```

However our site is written using HTML5 and contains elements like <HEADER>, which creates a warning when ZF internally calles DomDocument::loadHtml() on the output:

```
1) LoginControllerTest::testLoginFormIsShown
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 8
```

How can I either tell ZF not to pass this error through, or get PHPUnit to not regard the Warning as an error?  I don't want to turn down error reporting for the whole test suite.

**EDIT:**

Adding @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning to the test method supresses the failure, but hides any subsequent errors (and in fact doesn't even run the query).

**EDIT AGAIN:**

There doesn't seem to be a sensible resolution to this so I've ended up adding an @ in front of the breaking assertions for now.

Comment: Are you using Zend_View and if so, is the value of the view's doctype set to Zend_View_Helper_Doctype::HTML5?

Comment: Cez - yeah it is, I'll file this as a ZF bug.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `DOMDocument` takes issue with html5. You can try Xpath:

```
$this->assertXpath("//form[@id = 'login']");
```

Comment: XPath seems to also call ->loadHtml() first so the DomDocument warning is passed through to PHPUnit.